# Did this drive die?

Tags: disk, ssd-hdd-hybrid

I am having issues with Seagate Laptop SSHD 1TB, PN: [ST1000LM014-1EJ164-SSHD-8GB](http://www.harddrivebenchmark.net/hdd.php?hdd=Seagate%20ST1000LM014-1EJ164-SSHD-8GB&id=9894).

```
dmesg | grep ata1:
```

says this:

```
[    1.197516] ata1: SATA max UDMA/133 abar m2048@0xf7d36000 port 0xf7d36100 irq 31
[    6.548436] ata1: link is slow to respond, please be patient (ready=0)
[   11.232622] ata1: COMRESET failed (errno=-16)
[   16.588832] ata1: link is slow to respond, please be patient (ready=0)
[   21.269019] ata1: COMRESET failed (errno=-16)
[   26.621223] ata1: link is slow to respond, please be patient (ready=0)
[   56.322386] ata1: COMRESET failed (errno=-16)
[   56.322449] ata1: limiting SATA link speed to 3.0 Gbps
[   61.374591] ata1: COMRESET failed (errno=-16)
[   61.374651] ata1: reset failed, giving up
```

Further, I don't see the drive in GParted.

Does this mean this drive is dead or semi-dead?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the issue is with the link, rather than an actual error reported by the drive itself, technically it means that either the SATA port, or the SATA cable, or the drive is having issues. In all likelihood though the drive is dead. (But try another cable if you have one!)

Comment: I had this same `COMRESET failed` error this week, I wiggled the cable and problem gone!

Comment: I tried reconnecting the cable, but the drive had been working for the last couple of months so I was thinking that's probably not it. An interesting side effect in my case, the keyboard doesn't get initialized properly so I could not use the Del or F2 keys to enter the BIO and check the list of drives there. Removing the drive and things worked as expected.

Comment: I just had this error and found the data cable was completely disconnected from the mother board. How does that even happen? I made sure it clipped in this time.

Answer (score 1):

I just spent a few hours trying to solve this same error. I only noticed it in the logs because I was debugging an unrelated issue; the system was still able to boot into Debian even with the "COMRESET failed (errno=16)" error.

I was convinced it wasn't a hardware issue but after moving sda's cable from SATA0 to any other port it was gone. I proved it to SATA0 by booting with every other combo available and trying different cable/drive combos in SATA0; the error was only thrown with that port in use.

Mobo is a Pegatron IPISB-CH2 (donor from a HP h8-1250ea) for reference.